# SVN keeps prompting me for passwords and refuses to cache my credentials

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, ubuntu, ssh

Environment : Eclipse Indigo, Ubuntu 11.04, Subclipse 1.6
SVN Clients : Subclipse, RabbitVCS

I'm connecting via svn+ssh. My URL looks like :

svn+ssh://[MY NAME]@[MY DOMAIN]/[PATH]

I can connect to the repo just fine. The problem is that every time I try to communicate with the repo, it prompts me for a password.  Really annoying!

I get the impression that SVN has the ability to cache passwords -- I've read that's what the ./subversion/auth folder is for.  However, my ./subversion/auth folder contains four empty folders.

I've experienced this behavior with both Subclipse and RabbitVCS.

Is there any way to force SVN to cache my credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Public Key Authentication with SSH:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

It will enable you to used **svn over ssh** without entering a password every single time, with help of a [common SSH agent](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeKeyring/Ssh).

Subversion itself [caches credentials only to servers using HTTP/DAV](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ssh-auth-cache).

Comment: Note that if you choose to use a password with your ssh keys, it will still prompt you for it, no caching

Comment: Awesome.  I was confused because my coworker got his machine to cache his credentials, but it looks like he has a keypair set up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this may help to someone. Check whether ~/.subversion folder is owned by wrong user, so it may be read-only to user who is using it.

```
sudo chown -R your_username:your_group ~/.subversion
```