# How to configure ssh key for svn repository in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, svn, ssh

I am trying to configure SSH key for svn repository (svn://username@hostname).
1. Generate key using ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. copy public key to server using ssh-copy-id user@hostname

But still it asking for password while checking out from svn repository.

Comment: Are you able to checkout after entering the password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN keeps prompting me for passwords and refuses to cache my credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086797/svn-keeps-prompting-me-for-passwords-and-refuses-to-cache-my-credentials)

Comment: Yes i am able to checkout after entering password but i want to checkout without entering password using ssh key conf.

Comment: you need to `ssh-add` to add to ssh-agent